# How android select icon size

Tags: android, icons

I tried below on HTC desire and got 240 48 160 48.

So can anyone help on my doubts:
1. The UI guideline suggests 72px for the icon. Why do I get 48px for standard? And why system load my 48px icon rather than 72px? 
2. What is resources.getDisplayMetrics()? Why is it different from getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm)?

```
    final DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    float den = dm.density;
    int dpi = dm.densityDpi;

    final Resources resources = getResources();
    final DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt)).setText(Float.toString(den) 
            + " " + Integer.toString(dpi)
            + " " + Integer.toString((int)     getResources().getDimension(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size))
            + " " + Integer.toString(metrics.densityDpi)
            + " " + Integer.toString(bd.getIntrinsicHeight()));
```